# Generate average for ratings in Django models and return with other model

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-2.0

I'm working on a project using Python(3.7) and Django(2.1) in which I'm trying to implement a rating system.

> **Note:** I have searched a lot and taken a look at various related questions but couldn't find any solution to my specific problem, so don't mark this as duplicated, please!

I have two models as:

**From `models.py`:**

```
class Gig(models.Model):
    CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
        ('GD', 'Graphic & Design'),
        ('DM', 'Digital Marketing'),
        ('WT', 'Writing & Translation'),
        ('VA', 'Video & Animation'),
        ('MA', 'Music & Audio'),
        ('PT', 'Programming & Tech'),
        ('FL', 'Fun & Lifestyle'),
    )

    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    price = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
    photo = models.FileField(upload_to='gigs')
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class GigReview(models.Model):
    RATING_RANGE = (
        ('1', '1'),
        ('2', '2'),
        ('3', '3'),
        ('4', '4'),
        ('5', '5')
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    gig = models.ForeignKey(Gig, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='rates')
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    rating = models.IntegerField(choices=RATING_RANGE,)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.content
```

**From `views.py`:**

```
def home(request):
    gigs = Gig.objects.filter(status=True)
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'gigs': gigs})
```

So, every `Gig` has many reviews and I want to return the `average` rating for each gig to the template, how Can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple annotation should get it done in one query (rather than one per `Gig` when using a property):

```
from django.db.models import Avg

gigs = (Gig.objects
    .filter(status=True)
    .annotate(avg_review=Avg('rates__rating'))
)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to be able to access the average review value on model level, you could add a property field that aggregates the average value through related models in the `Gig`-model:

```
class Gig(models.Model):
    ...

    @property
    def average_rating(self):
        return self.rates.all().aggregate(Avg('rating')).get('rating__avg', 0.00)
        # Change 0.00 to whatever default value you want when there
        # are no reviews.
```

And in the template access the value with `average_rating`.

Comment: it's displaying as `{'rating__avg': 3.5}` in template, how I can I only display the value?

Comment: @AbdulRehman I've updated my answer to return the value only. Basically you just add `.get('rating__avg', 0.00)` at the end of the aggregation.